Free screen recorder with basic editing
I want to record my screen on Windows 10. I did a little research, but didn't find a tool that satisfies all of these criteria yet:

Free
Basic editing features (just cut a little)
No complex interface (OBS, sorry, you're eliminated)

Can you please suggest at least one option?

If you can accept a .GIF output format, you may find that Screen2Gif does what you require, without an overwhelming interface.

As shown in the image above, from the linked site, the opening screen is about as basic as one could ask.
The screenshots page provides a bit more of the basics, covering screen capture, web capture, user created images akin to Paint, etc.

Thank you! I'm not a big fan of GIFs, though. Are there apps that output WMVs or the like?

there are GIF to MP4 converters, as well as GIF to WMV converters, according to a quick internet search

There are, but that extra step makes the whole process less convenient overall

I've found that when one seeks free-of-cost, one must necessarily make certain concessions. I use a single step converter, but it's not free and it's not as basic as the one posted as an answer. Good luck in your search.

@SergeyZolotarev: Note that despite its name, ScreenToGif appears to be well capable of writing to video formats such as mp4, without any extra steps as far as I can tell.

I'd say ShareX (https://getsharex.com/) is a great capture program, while for editing I use OpenShot (https://www.openshot.org/).
I don't think there's an all-in-one program that fits the requirements.
